# Como obter o mesmo valor?

Tags: delphi

Tenho um codigo em delphi que é responsavel por uma comuniçao ESC/POS com uma impressora matricial...o Comando é composto da seguinte maneira:

```
var
    comando : AnsiString;
    pL, pH : AnsiString;
begin
  pL := #147; //96
  pH := #2;   //2
  comando := #29+#40+#76+pL+pH+#48+#67+#48+ #32  +#32   +#1+#72+#0+ #68+#0+#49 + hexa;

end;
```

Eu gostaria de pegar os valores de pL e pH de um edit.
Se o usuario digita no edit '147', eu tentei converter isso para inteiro. Ex:

```
pL := 147;
```

Mas acredito eu que pL := #147 e pL := 147 sejam diferentes, pois o comando nao funcionou da segunda forma.

Como eu faço essa conversão?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer assim:

```
pL := Chr(StrToInt(SeuEdit.Text));
```

Tente e depois nos diga se funcionou.